# byte counters for MAC address using IPTABLES

Tags: linux, command-line, iptables

Assuming that I am the Server, and I want to watch bandwidth of downloading and uploading for the specific MAC address. With the uploading monitor chain. I use this: 

`iptables -N clientA_upload` and then `iptables -A FORWARD -m mac --mac-source 00:11:22:33:44:55:66` and it works just fine. 
- But when it comes to the downloading chain. I use `iptables -A FORWARD -m mac --mac-destination 00:11:22:33:44:55:66` and the iptables doesn't support the mac-destination. Please help me out

P/s: I just want to monitor by MAC address. Not ip address. Because in android OS. It doesn't support byte countering using IP address. So please help !!!

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as `--mac-destination`. You have to [move to ebtables for that](http://lists.netfilter.org/pipermail/netfilter/2005-April/060051.html).

Comment: I can't find it either

Answer (score 1):

For the missing `--mac-destination` the trick is to combine iptables `--mac-source` with `CONNMARK`:

- First use `--mac-source` to match packets coming from the mac address you're interested in.
- use `CONNMARK` to mark the whole connection, ie both directions (!) and
- now check packets going in the other direction with the connection mark.

```
# lan interface
if_lan=eth0

# packets going to mac address will pass through this:
iptables -t mangle -N clientA_download    

# mark connections involving mac address:
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -i $if_lan -m state --state NEW -m mac --mac-source 00:11:22:33:44:55 -j CONNMARK --set-mark 1234

# match packets going to mac address:
iptables -t mangle -A POSTROUTING -o $if_lan -m connmark --mark 1234 -j clientA_download
```

Initially i thought this would only work for tcp connections originating from the lan, but given the definition of `--state NEW` it should work in both directions for both tcp and udp (!)

For counters see also `ipset` which is very nice for this.

[Policy Routing on Linux based on Sender MAC Address](https://linuxmonk.ch/wordpress/index.php/2016/policy-routing-on-linux-based-on-sender-mac-address/) was the inspiration for this answer.

Answer (score -2):

You are confusing downloading and uploading rules.

**Rule 1:**     `iptables -A FORWARD -m mac --mac-source 00:11:22:33:44:55:66`

is appended to the ipchain and checks the given mac in forwarding chain.

Now you need to check your mac in input chain, so instead of applying the second rule in `FORWARD` chain, apply it in `INPUT` chain:

**Rule 2:**    `iptables -I INPUT -m mac --mac-destination 00:11:22:33:44:55:66`

Comment: Isn't the INPUT chain is for our device. What I mean here is I want to watch the bandwidth of a client (His MAC is 00:11:22:33:44:55:66) while I am the Server (My MAC is AA:BB:CC:DD:EE). There are 2 kind of streams. Download stream and Upload stream via me in between (The Internet, Me, Client).